# State button selector android

Tags: android, xml, button

I need to use a state button selector. I have read some artcicles on internet about this subject, but it still doesn't work.

Button code(from the layout):

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_shoot"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"/>
```

Selector code(drawable):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Thank's for your futures answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this tutorial.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Prepare 3 images for button states, and put it into “resource/drawable” folder.

- button_normal_green.png – Default image button.
- button_focused_orange.png – Display when button is focused, for
  example, when phone’s keypad is move (focus) on this button.
- button_pressed_yellow.png – Display when button is pressed.

Now, create a new XML file in “res/drawable/” folder, in whatever name you want, in this case, we just give a name as “new_button.xml“. This file defined which button state is belong to which image.

Now, you can refer to this button via this Id : @drawable/new_button.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
    </selector>
```

Open “res/layout/main.xml” file, add a normal button, and attach the background image to above “new_button” via “android:background="@drawable/new_button”.

You may also use some shapes in place of images.Create three different shapes for three different button states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"/>
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:centerColor="#7995A8"
    android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:type="linear"/>
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"/>
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"/>
</shape>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I followed this tutorial, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: may i know what have you tried, so that i can help you.

Comment: I use the solution that I wrote in the question, your solution and plenty of other found on the internet. But the pressed state in the selector is always ignored. I tried to do this in  programmatical way, it's work fine. But when you pressed on the button and you slide your finger out of the button(you still press the screen), the phone keep it pressed.